# Change embedded image type in APIC ID3 tag via Mutagen

Tags: python, mp3, id3, mutagen, apic

I have a large music library which I have just spent around 30 hours organizing. For some of the MP3 files, I embedded the cover art image as type 0 (Other) and I'd like to change it to type 3 (Front Cover). Is there a way to do this in Python, specifically in Mutagen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I was able to pull it off.

First, get access to the file in Mutagen:

```
audio = MP3("filename.mp3")
```

Then, get a reference to the tag you're looking for:

```
picturetag = audio.tags['APIC:Folder.jpg']
```

Then, modify the `type` attribute:

```
picturetag.type = 3
```

Then, assign it back into the audio file, just to be sure

```
audio.tags['APIC:Folder.jpg'] = picturetag
```

Finally, save it!

```
audio.save()
```

And you're there! The APIC tag comes with its own class that sports everything you'd need to modify pictures and picture tagging info. Happy music organizing!